# How to setup DVWA on localhost - windows 11

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, localhost

[image]

**Error**

```
Fatal error:
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception:
Unknown database 'dvwa' in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php:499
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php(499): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'USE dvwa')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\login.php(8): dvwaDatabaseConnect()
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvwa\dvwa\includes\dvwaPage.inc.php on line 499
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]. And please let us know what you've already tried, as _"Unknown database 'dvwa'"_ is quite a self-descriptive error message

Answer (score 0):

1. Change this in `config.inc.php`

   ```
   $_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
   $_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'dvwa';
   ```
2. Go to `phpmyadmin` page: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php
3. Create a new user `dvwa` with all privileges. (see steps below)
4. Go to http://127.0.0.1/login.php
5. Enter username `dvwa` and press `login`.

To create a new user:

1. click on `User accounts`
2. click on `Add new user`
3. set username to `dvwa` and password to `no password`
4. check `Create database with same name and grant all privileges`
5. check all `global privileges`
6. press `Go`

[image]